# Zend Framework lock row query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, innodb

That is my query:

```
 try {
        $this->_db->beginTransaction();

        $this->_db->update($this->_name, $data, $where);

        $this->_db->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_db->rollback();

        throw $e;
    }
```

I wanna if some user use this query, this row in table to be locked and when the query is finished to be unlocked. But, now if two users use this query at same time, thay can update this row. My table is InnoDB.

Exp.
If some user use this query to update news with id=10 and in this moment other user use this query to update same news(id=10).Next update one of the users will not be able to see new news information.

Comment: If you only have one update command in your transaction, you don't need to use transaction as it's already atomic

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB tables use row-level locking automatically. From [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual: 8.10.1 Internal Locking Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html):

> MySQL uses row-level locking for InnoDB tables to support simultaneous write access by multiple sessions, making them suitable for multi-user, highly concurrent, and OLTP applications.

Therefore, two rows cannot be written to simultaneously. Subsequent queries simply get queued until they are ready to be executed. (The same is true of MyISAM and other table types, but they use table-level locking.) You do not need to modify your code.

Comment: Ok, but some user use this query to update news with id=10 and in this moment other user use this query to update same news(id=10), but one of the users will not be able to see new news information.